# Magento after upgrading from 1.6 to 1.9,Google analytics report shows zero visitors

Tags: php, magento, google-analytics-api

i had upgraded my website from magento 1.6 to 1.9.0.1,and when i checked the google analytics report of our website for this month , it is showing 0 visitors.How could be it happen, did i need to change any thing in the code for this

Comment: Check that your analytics code is still loaded, I'm not familar with magento, it may load as a plugin/module. Check that it is still installed and enabled.

Comment: after upgrading my magento its selected as universal analytics, and i had changed it  to google analytics on today,